# Compare Flag Enums by Description

Tags: c#

I have the following enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserRoles {

  [Description("Gestor")]
  Admin = 1 << 0,

  [Description("Editor")]
  Editor = 1 << 1,

  [Description("Membro")]
  Member = 1 << 2
}
```

And then I have:

```
String[] currentUserRoles = new String[] { "Gestor, "Membro" }

UserRoles testRoles = UserRoles.Admin | UserRoles.Editor;
```

I would like to test if any of the testRoles are included in currentUserRoles.

The problem is that currentUserRoles are the Description attribute.

I was able to solve this using

```
UserRoles role;
currentUserRoles.Select(x => x.Value).Any(y => (Enum.TryParse(y, true, out role) && testRoles.HasFlag(role)));
```

But I would like to use the Description attribute to compare.

How can I do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result =
   Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRoles))
       .Cast<UserRoles>()
       .Where(r => (r & testRoles) == r)
       .Select(r => typeof(UserRoles).GetField(r.ToString())
                                     .GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
                                     .Description)
       .Intersect(currentUserRoles)
       .Any();
```

Comment: Very compact, very obscure :)
Why not just say that what one needs is the 
typeof(UserRoles).GetField(r.ToString()).GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description

Comment: @zverev.eugene so you're basically saying that providing a 6-ish line complete answer is strictly worse than providing the most essential part from it? As for the level of obscurity - I guess it depends on how familiar you're with LINQ - to me it's more readable than a blown-out loop.